# How to convert a formatted string to float in java with different locales?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a number with string type e.g. "1,000.00" in (EN) and the same value "1 000,00" in (FR).

how can I convert this string to float (e.g. 1000.00).

is there a method to do this in java or do I have to implement a getFloat(str,locale) my self.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DecimalFormat will do it.  Read [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for details.

Comment: ok, but this for converting from float to string.
I want to convert an already formatted string like (123 111,32) to a float (123111.32)!

Comment: Quote: " It has a variety of features designed to make it possible to *parse* and format numbers in any locale, including support for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits."  See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition)