# Formatting a number String according to format String

Tags: java, format

I have a String representing a number (e.g. 1234.56) and a String representing a format (e.g. 1,234.56 or 1 234.56 or 1234,56...) and need to format the number String according to the format String. Both Strings are given.

Some code for better underdstanding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number = "1000.0";
    formatNumber(number, "1,234.56"); //Should be 1,000.00
    formatNumber(number, "1 234.56"); //Should be 1 000.00
    formatNumber(number, "1234,56"); //Should be 1000,00
}

public static String formatNumber(String number, String format) {
    return ???
}
```

Whats the best way to achieve that?

Thanks 
Paul

Comment: use decimal format as menthioned in this thread [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376226/how-to-convert-a-formatted-string-to-float-in-java-with-different-locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three lines should do.

```
String pattern = format.replaceAll("\\d", "#");
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
return myFormatter.format(value);
```

I am writing by heart, so write back if you encounter problems